# gsettings and anacron

Tags: dbus, gsettings, anacron

I wrote a script to change my desktop background. I want this script to run on anacron because I often turn my computer off at night. I've tested parts of the script, and I think the problem is with this line:

```
DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri '"file://'$wallPath'"'
```

(`$wallPath` is the wallpaper path)

It switches my wallpaper but it doesn't when anacron runs. I figured this was because anacron runs as root (I also check dconf for root and my user to check this). So I hacked up a way to run anacron as a specific user. But that didn't work.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to run gsettings as a user? I've tried su (username) -c 'sh run/this/script' to no avail. I've found some stuff about exporting some dbus env variables, but I'm having difficulty following it.

Answer (score 0):

As root, a simple `sudo -u <username> <command>` will do.

Comment: this is one of the first things i tried. unfortunately, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a separate anacron instance to run in user mode. To do so create a `.anacron` folder in your home directory and in it two subfolders, `etc` and `spool`.

Then proceed to create a new `anacrontab` in your newly created `~/.anacron/etc` folder with the following contents:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

1   10    wallpaperchanger script.sh
```

where script.sh is the path to your script (or a one-liner, your choice). Configure the intervall and delay to your pleasure and save the file as `anacrontab`.

Then add the following line to your `~/.profile` file:

```
/usr/sbin/anacron -s -t ${HOME}/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S ${HOME}/.anacron/spool
```

Anacron should be up and running on next login.

**Note**: make sure `$wallPath` is a sane file path as you didn't account for spaces and special characters in your script.

Comment: So I have this set up. I know the script is working. But the gsettings set command isnt working. Do you know of any place I can see the gsettings log?

Comment: Well, you could redirect the STDOUT of your command to a logfile, e.g. by adding `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri '"file://'$wallPath'"' > "$HOME/log.txt"`

Comment: @yoshi Also, I just noticed that I have a similar script I haven't used for a while. But I think I remember it working quite well back in the day. This is it: `export DISPLAY=:0; GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $URI`

Comment: okay so i see what the problem is. I'm having the problem listed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1033034
As soon as I hit 'change wallpaper' the background changes. gsettings are set appropriately and everything. just the background doesn't change. I've tried adding DISPLAY and GSETTINGS_BACKEND declarations before gsetting, but it still won't switch automatically

Comment: How about this idea then: Instead of changing the background via gsettings, why not set the $wallpath once and then compose a script to change the file $wallpath points to. This might work.

Comment: That's a good idea. But fortunately -- i don't have to use it :) So I noticed the guy in the launchpad site mentioned that the bug 'went away'. I turned off automatic updates so I guessed this might be the difference. Viola! So for anyone who comes upon this site: if you're running ubuntu 12.04 -- just update and use the DISPLAY & GSETTINGS_BACKEND declarations to get gsettings working with anacron. Thanks MHC for your help.

Comment: @yoshi No problem, I'm glad everything worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```bsh
DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri '"file://'$wallPath'"
```

try to use:

```bsh
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)  # instead of 'gnome-session' it can be also used 'noutilus' or 'compiz' or the name of a process of a graphical program about that you are sure that is running after you log in the X session
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri '"file://'$wallPath'"
```

See the explanation in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729/2353900).